# issue uploading images with ionic 3

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, camera, ionic3, image-upload

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tph5Nk4Ab1g) to upload images to my server with Ionic 3  ,

The image capture works: I can take pictures from gallery and show them. However, when I click in upload image button, in chrome of course without images I see a image file is created in the folder , but when I used Android Studio the image appear in the page but when I click on upload button, nothing happens and in the console of Android Studio this message appears:

```
    W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1822 : ERROR
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1822)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1822)
W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I/chatty: uid=10079(io.ionic.starter) identical 16 lines
W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code recently, and it worked like a charm

https://github.com/ralscha/blog/blob/master/uploadsb/client/src/pages/home/home.ts